# '*' operator is concatinating instead of multiplying - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have a CSV file read as `'keywords'` with contents :-

```
days    1
day     1
year    365
years   365
month   30
months  30
weeks   7
week    7
```

I am reading it as a list.

I have another CSV file with contents :-

```
for thirty working days
for 30 working weeks
upto 40 months
till 5 weeks
for a period of 30 years
for a period of 30.36 days
for 30working
21 to 30#@ period days
30#@ period weeks
for a period of 30-36 weeks
3 weeks after sixty
```

I have a function(`split_line`) which will convert the 'thirty' to '30' and give the string back into a variable `'WordasNumber'`..

What I am doing is find if there is `'days' or 'weeks' or 'months' or 'years'` in the content of the string being read from WordasNumber...

If there is `day` then multiply the number in that string with 1...if there is `week` then multiply the number in the string with 7...like wise multiply with 365 for `year` and with 30 for `month`

**My Code**

```
import csv
import re
from word2number import w2n

with open("test_term.csv", "rb") as file1:
        reader = csv.reader(file1)
        extractedlist = list(reader)

def split_line(text):
    words = text.split(' ')
    number = 0
    #print words
    # for each word in the line:
    new_list = []
    for word in words:
        #print word
        #print w2n.word_to_num(word)
        conversion = w2n.word_to_num(word)
        if isinstance(conversion, (int,long)):
            #print conversion
            new_list.append(conversion)
            number = conversion            

        else:
            if word.isdigit():
                number = word
            new_list.append(word)


    return new_list, number
numbersProcessed = []
for extraRow in extractedlist:
    pnO = extraRow[0]
    extraRow[1] = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', extraRow[1])
    if pnO in numbersProcessed:
        continue
    WordasNumber, number = split_line(extraRow[1])
    with open("dict.csv") as rawFile:
        reader = csv.reader(rawFile)
        keywords = list(reader)
        #print number
        #WordasNumber = re.match(r'[0-9]{3,}',WordasNumber).group()
    for a in WordasNumber:
        for line in keywords:
            #print line
            if(a==line[0]):
                value = line[1]
                #print value
                #print number
                try:

                    result = int(number)*int(value)
                    print pnO, ":" ,result
                    numbersProcessed.append(pnO)
                except:
                    pass
```

but the output I am getting is :-

```
30
30303030303030
404040404040404040404040404040404040404040404040404040404040
5555555
3030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030
0
21
0
0
420
```

I see that for the last string the `sixty` is getting converted to `60` and being multiplied with `7` and giving the output `420`...BUT why are other entries getting concatenated instead of multiplying?

the `30` is suppose to multiply with `365` is getting concatenated 365 times...not sure where I am going wrong...HELP!

Note:- ignore the 0s in the output as i understand its because there is no space in between the number and the string following it...but yeah if you have a quick solution to fix it then its welcome!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that's because 30 is a string, and you accidentally activated string multiplication.

```
"30" * 3 = "303030"
```

You need to cast your value to integer before multiplying.

Fix it from the source: in your `split_line`, instead of doing this:

```
if word.isdigit():
    number = word
```

do

```
if word.isdigit():
    number = int(word)
```

Comment: that fixed it..thank you..can you think of a solution for getting the output for strings which are giving output 0 now?

Comment: not sure but maybe you should replace `text[0].split(' ')` by simply `text[0].split()`, that will avoid to create empty fields if there are more than 1 space.

Comment: for the 0 stuff, will check later, no time now. But the `30.36` fails the `isdigit()` test for instance.

Comment: Do get back to me if you successfully fix those cases..i can wait..thank you for your time..

Comment: sorry I hadn't took the time to reply. I found your message again, will check tomorrow.

Comment: I could help you but I'm missing the code for `w2n.word_to_num`

Comment: i have updated the code...word2number has to be imported...its a library file

Comment: This is very dangerous code as it will skip any fractions.